# How do I get access to objects of another class?

Tags: python, class, oop, object

So I want to implement two classes `JobQueue` and `Process`. The idea is that `JobQueue` manages the objects of type `Process` and prioritizes the objects with the shortest processing time. So the first attribute shall represent the ID of the process and the second attribute shall be the processing time, both being integers. How does my class `Jobqueue` get access to these objects from the other class?

```
>>>class Process:

     def __init__(self,pid,procTime):
       self.pid=str(pid)
       self.procTime=procTime
>>>p1=Process(1234,55)
>>>p2=Process(4544,34)

>>>class JobQueue:

     queue=[]
     def insert(p): #how can I insert a certain object that I created before (p1 or p2)?
     queue.append([p.pid,p.procTime])
```

Some help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** Here are some examples what the code should do in the end:

```
>>>p1=Process(5234,60)
>>>p2=Process(8824,17)
>>>p2=Process(2291,34)
>>>j=JobQueue()
>>>j.extractMin() #Giving me the minimum of the queue and deletes it. If it is empty, the output shall be float('inf')
inf
>>>j.insert(p1) #the method insert inserts the objects to the queue
>>>j.insert(p3)
>>>print(j.minimum()) #prints the ID with the shortest processing time of all objects
2291
>>>j.decreaseKey(p1,23) #replaces the current processing time of p1 by 23
>>>print(j.minimum())
5234
>>>j.insert(p2)
>>>print(j.extractMin())
8824
>>>print(j.extractMin())
5234
>>>print(j.minimum())
2291
```

I guess these are enough examples to give you an insight what kind of code I want to write.

Comment: This is of course not the whole code I want to write, there are many methods that have to be added. I only wrote down where I'm stuck right now.

Comment: Is `JobQueue` static? Why don't you just append to `queue` in `Process.__init__`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are pretty much there already. Just pass your objects as arguments to your method. That is, you pass the `Process` objects to `JobQueue.insert`(or rather to an object created from that class). However, when defining a method the first argument is always `self`. Thus, you have to write like:

```
class JobQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue=[] # This gives a unique queue for each object

    def insert(self, p):
        self.queue.append([p.pid,p.procTime])
```

Also, you can consider storing the `Process` object `p` as it is in your queue, rather than its different parts:

```
    def insert(self, p):
        self.queue.append(p)
```

That way you can access all of the `Process` objects, including functions to update process times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added some examples. For what I want to do doesn't it make more sense to put all the objects into one queue to make it easier comparing them? 
I just started working with classes and objects, not familiar with it yet. What do you mean by storing the Process object p instead of its different parts (I know what you mean by it, but how?)

Comment: I have updated the example to show how you store the objects, or rather, references to them.

Comment: Oh okay I can just append the object just as any usual item. Thanks!

Comment: But regarding what I need to code should I give a unique queue for each object?

Comment: You will most likely only have one `JobQueue` meaning that in practice it does not matter if it is unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert in the init method of your job queue:

```
class Process:

    def __init__(self,pid,procTime):
        self.pid=str(pid)
        self.procTime=procTime



class JobQueue:

    def __init__(self,procs = None):

        self.queue = []
        for p in procs:
            self.insert(p)

    def insert(p):
        self.queue.append([p.pid,p.procTime])

p1=Process(1234,55)
p2=Process(4544,34)
a = JobQueue(procs = [p1, p2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
class Process:
    def __init__(self,pid,procTime):
        self.pid=str(pid)
        self.procTime=procTime

class JobQueue:
    queue=[]
    def insert(self,p): 
        self.queue.append([p.pid,p.procTime])

p = Process(1,2)
jq=JobQueue()
jq.insert(p)
print (jq.queue)
```

The OP:

```
[['1', 2]]
```